# ReactJS: Dynamically add tags and content to react-dom and reload it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spectacle

I am kind of new to reactJS and I am building a react app presentation with the help of [spectacle](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle/blob/master/README.md#base-props). The content and amount of slides for the presentation are not known beforehand. Therefore, the basic idea is that at the beginning the app fetches data from a server. This data contains the content of the different slides. As there can be different types of slides, a template is stated as well. (There are 3 type of templates already defined in the app).

So what I am doing right now is: I am fetching the data and iterate over them. I check for the type of template a create a Slide Element for each of them. I then append the Slide Elements to the Deck. However, whenever I try to get the Deck it seems to be null and I cannot append anything to it. The next step would be to reload the whole react-dom with the new Deck-Content.

Additionally, I think that this is definitely not the way of doing it but I don't know how to do it better. So my question is: am I doing it right? Is there a better way? What do I do wrong?

Here is my Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Deck, Slide } from 'spectacle';
// import createTheme from 'spectacle/lib/themes/default';
import Template1 from '../Templates/template#1/template1';
import Template2 from '../Templates/template#2/template2';
import Template3 from '../Templates/template#3/template3';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class FullDeck extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: null,
            text: null
        }
        const defaultBackground = 'https://blog.visme.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/50-Beautiful-and-Minimalist-Presentation-Backgrounds-08.jpg';
    }

   componentDidMount() {

    fetch(' http://localhost:3030/getSlides')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json()
      }).then(data => this.processResults(JSON.parse(data)));

    }

    processResults(data) {
        const slideDeck = document.getElementById('slideDeck');
        console.log(slideDeck)
        data.forEach(slide => {
            let element;

            if(slide.type === 'template1') {
                element = (
                    <Slide bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}>
                        <Template1 title={slide.title} text={slide.text}></Template1>
                    </Slide>
                )
                slideDeck.append(element);
            } else if(slide.type === 'template2') {
                element = (
                    <Slide bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}>
                        <Template2 title={slide.title} text={slide.text} slideImg={slide.img}></Template2>
                    </Slide>
                )
                slideDeck.append(element);
            } else if(slide.type === 'template3') {
                element = (
                    <Slide bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}>
                        <Template3 title={slide.title} slideImg={slide.img}></Template3>
                    </Slide>
                )
                slideDeck.append(element);
            }
        })
        ReactDOM.render(slideDeck, document.getElementById('root'));
    }

    render() {
    const defaulText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ";
    const slideImg = "https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/some.svg";
        const graph = "https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/images/bar-graph-fruit.svg";

        return (
            <div id='root'>
              <Deck  id='slideDeck'>
              </Deck>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `ReactDOM.render` inside `processResults`, you could call it outside of the component from the start, and return `null` from the render method until your network request is complete. This way you can put the slides `data` in your component state and derive the JSX from that data in the render method.

Comment: @Tholle I kind of understand what you mean. However, as I am new to reactJS could you show me with pseudo code what you mean by putting the slide in the component state and the derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `ReactDOM.render` inside `processResults`, you could call it outside of the component from the start, and e.g. keep an empty `slides` array in your state until your network request is complete. This way you can put the slides `data` in your component state and derive the JSX from that data in the render method.

**Example**

```
class FullDeck extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: null,
    text: null,
    slides: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(" http://localhost:3030/getSlides")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ slides: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const { slides } = this.state;

    if (slides.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Deck>
        {slides.map((slide, index) => {
          if (slide.type === "template1") {
            return (
              <Slide
                key={index}
                bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}
              >
                <Template1 title={slide.title} text={slide.text} />
              </Slide>
            );
          } else if (slide.type === "template2") {
            return (
              <Slide
                key={index}
                bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}
              >
                <Template2
                  title={slide.title}
                  text={slide.text}
                  slideImg={slide.img}
                />
              </Slide>
            );
          } else if (slide.type === "template3") {
            return (
              <Slide
                key={index}
                bgImage={slide.backgroundImg || this.defaultBackground}
              >
                <Template3 title={slide.title} slideImg={slide.img} />
              </Slide>
            );
          }
        })}
      </Deck>
    );
  }
}

ReactDom.render(<FullDeck />, document.getElementById("root"));
```